# How to move lots of bundled emails from one bundle to another?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

Google Inbox comes with the great bundles feature. However, sometimes it mis-bundles some of my emails.

In there a way to move all those mis-bundled emails from one bundle to another, without manually selecting and moving one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can select one or two messages and in the "More" menu you have the option to "Filter messages like these" - this should allow you to filter through your messages using various criteria and perform bulk actions on them. Another way would be to read more into the search options, using boolean operators and filtering for texts in particular fields (From, To, CC and so on) and build specific filters.

After defining a filter, you can save it with specific actions to be performed on messages matching those criteria (move them somewhere, label them in a particular way, star them, move them directly to the archive and so on) and it will also ask you if you want to apply those rules on the XYZ selected conversations.

Comment: This sounds like Gmail not Inbox.